# Data binding to table with local storage data in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

Hi i am doing simple shopping cart application using angular 8. I have place order screen there i list out some products to be order with option for quantity refer images i attached. i list out the products from json data and binded to table   there i have a scenario called filling shopping items based on users previous orders.  for example if user previously ordered a pencil box, or a pen, i have those quantity counts & individual price details. i need those quantity counts to be displayed by default on their place order screen. EX pencil box have 10 quantities the value must be displayed in the row of pencil box quantity textbox. i am storing the previous order details in local storage. i dont know how to retrieve and displayed to quantity textbox. can anyone help me to do this things.

in my image i have quantity count 1 for product code 1000. i need that count need to displayed in next table of that particular product quantity textbox. like wise if i have more product quantities need to display vise versa. thanks to all

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Bjt.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can implement function in onChanges and make your table internal component with input data
in each changes you must detect that in localstorage
and also you can make data service for localstorage that has subject variable and you can subscribe each changes in table component

Comment: sorry i didn't understand.  this is my local storage returned data [{"order_id":"9ec3bd80-91fc-0138-c8e0-0cc47ac946e0","product_code":"1000","quantity":1,"id":null}].  i want to compare the product code with server returned json data and if product code matches i have to update the quantity count.

Comment: sample server returned json {"result":"success", "reason":"Operation completed successfully.",  "api":"get_menus","locked":false, "payload":[{ "macs_menu_id":"1047-2000000366",        "header_text":null,"total_price":"2.18","product_code":"1000",      menu_prod_cat":"WRIT", "quan_limit":0,} ]
}

Comment: you can implement custom table for you that component given data from parent component and has implemented from onChanges class then you can watch all changes of data and set that to localstorage, if you want you can share your code

Comment: i showed payload datas already in table. pls refer my attached image in question section

Comment: in that image you can see two tables. one is generated from the payload json data. another one is created from local storage returned data.

Comment: why you dont change count of your item that user can increase or decrease that in localStorage?

Comment: i am storing order details in local storage when user complete his/her order by clicking save order button. the increase and decrease process only available in commissary order table.  you fully understood my question?

Comment: no you confused me. please share your code and make me understand your question maybe i can help you

Comment: i am displayed two tables right? one table have product code with quantity value. the next table also same product code but quantity is showing as zero. i need to update the quantity value from table1 to table 2. like wise if i have more products in table 1 need to update in table 2 for all products. table 2 created from json data i shared above.  now you can clear i hope